# Convert Object to std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

I've got a simple noob question that I can't find an answer to:

In C++ how do you convert a regular object

```
int i;
```

into a `std::unique_ptr`?

```
std::unique_ptr<int> iptr = &i; //invalid
std::unique_ptr<int> iptr = static_cast<std::unique_ptr<int>>(&i); //invalid
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't. That object cannot be deleted by `delete`, which is what the `unique_ptr` is going to do. You need

```
auto iptr = make_unique<int>();
```

Here, we define make_unique as a utility function identical to make_shared, which should have been Standard but unfortunately was overlooked. Here's the implementation in brief:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: Though for completeness the function would be nice, but I don't think it was overlooked so much as not needed. Remember that make_shared solves a problem of allocating two objects at once (there is no equivalent constructor), whereas unique_ptr simply doesn't need this (it has zero overhead by design).

Comment: That's not true. There is still exception unsafety if you construct two unique_ptrs in one function call, for example, which make_unique saves.

Comment: Can you not avoid that by creating the unique_ptr directly at that point? `func( unique_ptr<T>(new T), unique_ptr<U>(new U) )`

Comment: Nope, it's still unsafe.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. `i` was not dynamically allocated so it doesn't need to be deleted. If you wrapped a smart pointer around its address, it would do `delete &i` at some point and give you undefined behaviour. You should only wrap something you have `new`ed in a smart pointer, like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(5));
```

The whole point of a smart pointer is that it manages the lifetime of a dynamically allocated object for you. `i` has automatic storage duration so will be destroyed at the end of its scope. You don't need anything to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work:

```
int i;
auto deleter = [](int *ptr){};
std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(deleter)> iptr(&i, deleter);
```

You have to provide a custom deleter that does nothing. The default deleter cannot delete an automatic variable not allocated by `new`. (However, this defeats the purpose of using a smart pointer, but shows that it is possible).

Answer (score 0):

When the unique_ptr will be destroyed what would happen ? Or the other way, when the variable gets out of scope ? It makes no sense actually